# Export sharepoint list data to excel using python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have sharepoint url where i can open and export that sharepoint list into excel. I want to automate that using python. i have tried many suggestions from online. but none of those are working.

i have tried below code to connect sharepoint

```
import requests
url= 'my sharepoint file path here'
r=requests.get(url,verify=False) #no username or password required
```

i am expecting the code should export sharepoint list data to new excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t done this myself with code, but I believe it should work similar to what’s been done in [SharePoint 2013: Export To Excel Using REST API](https://collab365.community/sharepoint-2013-export-to-excel-using-rest-api/)

What they do there is actually using a link to a query that Excel can understand with parameters as the list id and view id. Since they use code within the browser it recognizes the content type (.iqy file) as something that should be opened in Excel. Don’t know how that would be when dont in Python though.

Another thing: Unless you have anonymous access turned on in your site, you need to authenticate the request to SharePoint.